# What's the point of using performBlockAndWait in new iOS5 NSManagedObjectContext?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3

I am modifying my program to use the new iOS5 style.

So I simply use this code:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *threadContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
threadContext.parentContext = [self managedObjectContextMainThread];
//threadContext.persistentStoreCoordinator= [self persistentStoreCoordinator]; //moc.persistentStoreCoordinator;//  [moc persistentStoreCoordinator];
```

My new background ManagedObjectContext doesn't have a persistentStore but have parent store instead.\

After that I suppose I am supposed to add

performBlockAndWait on all operation where I use all operation that use the new MOC.

I don't use that and doing just fine at least so far

performBlockAndWait is done by executing the block at the **same thread** and wait till **it's complete**.

What's the difference between that and just type the code like usual?

I mean there has to be some used, but I am totally missing here.

I can understand performBlock. That'll be like executing something in back ground. Even then it's superseded with Global Central Dyspatch.

Yes there is this new thing called Queue. Okay, if we do something on the **same** thread, of course everything is done consecutively. Duh.... So why the queue?

Anyone care to explain?

Comment: DI you have more experience regarding it? I wrote a comment below, could you check it and answer it if you have any time?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the thread that execute the block is not the same with the thread that call performBlockAndWait.

For example, some core data object may only be able to be executed at main thread.

Hence, the performBlockAndWait would do it on a main thread (different thread) and block the current thread.

Also it's saver. Core data would lock things up appropriately preventing collision. If you have several thread accessing the same managed object context, you need to pull this up.

Comment: Even on the main thread when I'm using the main context I have to ember my code into a performBlockAndWait? It will be executed even on the main thread. And when I'm doing something on main thread with one MO fetched from the main context, than I should embed it into a performBlockAndWait?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for `performBlockAndWait:` is it will get and hold the concurrency lock to access Core Data. You can consider it a modernization of the `lock`/`unlock` approach, but that's undocumented implementation detail.

If you just execute the code directly, it won't do proper concurrency locking. This is interesting for a number of reasons:

1. Requests to Core Data won't be properly serialized. That is, if you `performBlock:` (no wait) the code could end up executing at the same time as other Core Data code, which would probably cause a problem in the coordinator or persistent store.
2. It… well, I actually don't think it *should* work. It seems to most of the time in practice, but **you're running Core Data without necessary locks**. Pretty sure you're into undocumented behaviour here at a minimum.

So:

- **`performBlockAndWait:` sets up an environment where your block can access Core Data via the context and waits for the block to complete.**

  - The documentation says nothing about the thread. It's not actually documented as running on the current thread.
  - Even if it doesn't now, it could be changed in the future to go to secondary threads in at least *some* circumstances.
  - Read the parent point again: That's what you're supposed to rely on. The rest is just details.
- **`performBlock:` sets up an environment where your block and access Core Data via the context and does not wait for the block to complete.**

  - The documentation says nothing about the thread. It's not actually documented as running on a different thread.
  - Although unlikely, a future version of the OS could decide to run the block on the current thread at a later time.
  - Again, the parent point is what you're to rely on. The rest is undocumented details.

I hope that helps. Basically, you're supposed to play dumber than you are when touching these calls. Let the OS do the right thing, just try not to make assumptions about what it's doing. :)

The `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` constant sets up too many expectations for how this works.